# PHP default input value won't change on save

Tags: php, wordpress

I had my site working as follows:

Input url in Wordpress options, save and it saves.
Now I want it so set a default value in the input (url of the server) and if I change and save it, on page re-load the new value should appear, not the default value.

**Before**

```
<label for="site">
    <strong>Site:</strong> 
    <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $this->getOption($options, 'url') ; ?>">
</label><em>
```

**My attempt**

I have now set a default value of the input to be that of the server url but obviously on page re-fresh it will display this value, just unsure how to fix this so if I update the input and press save, on page re-fresh it will retain my last input rather than updating it with the default value.

```
<label for="site">
    <strong>Site:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="url" value="http://<?php echo str_replace('www.','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); ?>/"/>
</label><em>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear on what you're trying to accomplish. The value of the input being set to that of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. Which code attempts to save the edited value?

Comment: You can't just output that and expect PHP to replace with something the next time just because it was changed on the browser. The browser has to tell PHP about the change and PHP has to act on that.

Comment: @popnoodles Thanks and I completely understand PHP must do something, just don't know what that is.. see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to set a variable to the original `$_SERVER` value.
If a value is posted from the form, set the variable to that value instead.
Then, use that variable to populate the input value, rather than the original `$_SERVER` value.

Something like this:

```
<?php

// this uses a ternary operator. if ? then : else.
// if value is posted set to that value, otherwise set to $_SERVER value

$url= !empty($_POST['url'])
       ? $_POST['url'] 
       : 'http://'.str_replace('www.','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

// show a message if data is posted (for debugging purposes)
if (!empty($_POST)) {echo "<p>Data was posted.</p>";}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

  <label>
    <strong>Site:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $url ?>" />
  </label>

</form>
```

Comment: Also when I update the "/" and save, it leaves it as that on page refresh.

Comment: Not sure what that would happen, but I changed my code to use `!empty()` rather than `!isset()`, just in case. Working here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wkg-4mb

Comment: sorry for the confusion, was actually a coding error on my behalf where I hadn't updated the name of the input! Sorry again. I have now accepted your answer, and thank you!